# Сборщик мусора

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!

Есть вопрос следующего характера: у меня в программе есть кэш, который чистится если maxMemory - totalMemory(значения берутся из рантаймов) меньше 10мб. Очистка кэша представляет собой обычное пересоздание некоторой структуры иодин из членов которых Image. При пересоздании image = null;тем не менее на определенном этапе у меня заканчивается память(java heap overflow).

Собственно вопрос: что неправильно я делаю, почему память со временем все равно заканчивается?

Comment: если заканчивается память то обычно проблема в :  
1) ваша програма сама по себе требует много ресурсов а вы запускаете JVM с стандартными настройками (погуглите 'java memory options' )  
2) у вас то что в языке "С" называется утечка памяти, - вы создаете много обьектов для хранения которых и тратится вся память (обычно проблема возникает если обьект создается в цикле + логическая ошибка в работе программы). сборщик мусора чистит память сам, но обьекты удаляются только если на них нет ссылок (это может означать что вы храните слишком много ненужных данных)

Comment: ^^ продолжение: если у вас правильный код, то решать проблему надо пункт 1 + см ответ @ArTeam (более оптимальное использование памяти при работе кэша)

Comment: Вполне возможно, что ваша ручная очистка памяти просто не успевает за созданием новых объектов и тогда случается бум. Надо вохложить эту работу на JVM, как предланает @ArTeam.

Comment: 10мб это очень мало. Но, думаю, дело не в этом, а в том, что на самом деле Вы память не освобождаете (ссылочки откуда-нибудь остаются).

Попробуйте чистить кэш постоянно (для теста) и если heap overflow, то ищите где они висят.

Comment: Вот как ни крути, а все-таки не хватает в джаве ручного ликвидатора объектов.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про стратегии обновления кэша и слабые и гибкие ссылки (например [здесь](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp11225/) и [здесь](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp01246/)).

Про стратегии кэширования можно [здесь](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/CachingStrategies) почитать.